# Getting "Error saving file" message (or) System.OutOfMemoryException (or) ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected

Tags: c#, excel

I have developed a Windows-Form application using C#.

The application will read an Excel file, store that values in to a Data Table, do some process and write that processed information in to a new Excel file.

No issues while writing < 400 rows, if it is > 400, then the application throws the exception `Error saving file` or `System.OutOfMemoryException` or `ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected`

Also showing the following error (inside the visual studio window):
`The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x592b88 to COM context 0x592cf8 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.`

```
worksheetToWrite.Cells["A" + Iteration1].Value = sMailID2.Trim();
worksheetToWrite.Cells["B" + Iteration1].Value = intCurrentBatchSize.ToString();

if (sFull1.Length <= 4000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, sFull1.Length);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 4000 && sFull1.Length <= 8000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, sFull1.Length - 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 8000 && sFull1.Length <= 12000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, sFull1.Length - 8000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 12000 && sFull1.Length <= 16000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(12000, sFull1.Length - 12000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 16000 && sFull1.Length <= 20000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(12000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(16000, sFull1.Length - 16000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 20000 && sFull1.Length <= 24000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(12000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(16000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(20000, sFull1.Length - 20000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 24000 && sFull1.Length <= 28000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(12000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(16000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(20000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(24000, sFull1.Length - 24000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 28000 && sFull1.Length <= 32000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(12000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(16000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(20000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(24000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(28000, sFull1.Length - 28000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 32000 && sFull1.Length <= 36000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(12000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(16000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(20000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(24000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(28000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(32000, sFull1.Length - 32000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = string.Empty;
}
else if (sFull1.Length > 36000 && sFull1.Length <= 40000)
{
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["C" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(0, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["D" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(4000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["E" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(8000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["F" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(12000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["G" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(16000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["H" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(20000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["I" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(24000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["J" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(28000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["K" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(32000, 4000);
    worksheetToWrite.Cells["L" + Iteration1].Value = sFull1.Substring(36000, sFull1.Length - 36000);
}
```

`Iteration1` denotes the rows. Am saving 4000 characters in each cell, except the cells in the first row and the first & second columns of each row.

Can anybody help me to solve it.

Comment: Is your datatable is of fixed rows?

Comment: No. I have read up to 3500 rows from Excel and stored it to the Data Table. No issues in reading. The error occurs only while writing.

Comment: Also now i am getting System.OutOfMemoryException

Comment: can you post the full error message? `System.OutOfMemoryException` on which line?

Comment: Why are you writing `string.Empty;`? can't you just omit those lines of code?

Comment: Have you tried saving the document while iterating? Say per 100 lines?

Comment: using (packageToWrite1 = new ExcelPackage(existingFileToWrite1))
{ packageToWrite1.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Lead Owners"); //Iteration done here; packageToWrite1.Save(); } //This is the code i used to save.

Comment: As we know, excel has limited rows. 65536 rows in excel 2003, 1048576 rows in excel 2007.just make sure in loop its not crossing these limits

Comment: @Venil Than perhaps you can try to save inside the iteration as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @Silvermind I am doing Save to Excel process with in the iteration. But still it throws the same error.

Comment: I have disposed all the Data-tables, String builders and some other objects before saving to Excel, but still the Memory usage is 3.28 GB and CPU usage is 42%,  While running the application.

Comment: I got a new error (ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected), updated it in the Explanation part.

Answer (score 0):

Previously i was saving the Excel file in each Iteration. Now i have created a new Data Table, consolidating all information (to be write in to Excel) to that Data Table. So all the iterations have been completed here before writing. After writing everything to the Workbook i am saving it.

It works fine now and no issues in handling the bulk amount of data.

code:

```
<pre>ExcelWorksheet worksheetToWrite = packageToWrite1.Workbook.Worksheets["Lead Owners"];

     for (int i = 0; i < dtSalesPersonSingleSB.Columns.Count; i++)
     {
       worksheetToWrite.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Value = dtSalesPersonSingleSB.Columns[i].ColumnName; //dtSalesPersonSingle.Columns[i].ColumnName;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < dtSalesPersonSingleSB.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
     // to do: format datetime values before printing
      for (int j = 0; j < dtSalesPersonSingleSB.Columns.Count; j++)
      {
        worksheetToWrite.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)].Value = dtSalesPersonSingleSB.Rows[i][j];
      }
     }
     packageToWrite1.Save();
```

Thanks for all your support to achieve the expected result.